# Reverse and add degeneracy

Tags: code-golf, number-theory, decision-problem

## Intro

Reverse and add is as simple as it sounds, take `n` and add it to its digits in reverse order. (e.g. 234 + 432 = 666).

If you apply this process repeatedly some numbers will eventually hit a prime number, and some will never reach a prime.

## Example

I currently have

11431 rep.

```
11431 is not prime
11431 + 13411 = 24842 which is not prime
24842 + 24842 = 49684 which is not prime
49684 + 48694 = 98378 which is not prime
98378 + 87389 = 185767 which is prime!
```

This number hits a prime

In contrast any multiple of 3 will never hit a prime, this is because the all multiples of 3 have a digit sum that is a multiple of 3 and vice versa.
Thus reverse and add on a multiple of 3 will always result in a new multiple of 3 and thus never a prime.

## Task

Take a positive integer `n` and determine if repeatedly reversing and adding will ever result in a prime number. Output a truthy or falsy value.  Either truthy for reaches a prime and falsy value for does not or the other way around both are acceptable.

Prime numbers will be considered to reach a prime number in zero iterations.

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so try to make your code as short as possible.

## Test Cases

True for reaches a prime false for never reaches a prime

```
11 -> True
11431 -> True
13201 -> True
13360 -> True
13450 -> True
1019410 -> True
1019510 -> True
22 -> False
1431 -> False
15621 -> False
14641 -> False
```

## Hint

While I was writing this challenge I discovered a cool trick that makes this problem a good deal easier.  It is not impossible without this trick and it is not trivial with it either but it does help.  I had a lot of fun discovering this so I will leave it in a spoiler below.

> Repeated reverse and add will always hit a multiple of 11 in 6 iterations or less.  If it does not hit a prime before it hits a multiple of 11 it will never hit a prime.

Comment: I find it more of a mathematical problem than a coding one. I guess code problems have specific rules laid out which are implemented in the code by the answerer; I don't think that's the case with this challenge.

Comment: @DobbyTheFree-Elf I think the difference between this problem and typical "coding" problems is that often for the latter, the algorithm to be implemented is obvious and it is just a matter of doing it in as little code as possible.  This challenge forces you to come up with a algorithm from scratch.  Both pose their own unique puzzles but both are ultimately still coding problems.

Comment: I agree with that comment of yours, but in my opinion, coming up with such algorithm present in this challenge is more of a job of a mathematician than a programmer. I don't know what others think, but that's at least what I think. So, this has my downvote.

Comment: @DobbyTheFree-Elf I hate to break it to you but finding efficient algorithms to solve a problem in a crucial part of being a good programmer.

Comment: I agree with that too. But the algorithm for this challenge will have more mathematical value. One will have to find or create proven mathematical theorems to guarantee a correct output with every possible input, which in my opinion what mathematicians do. Common approaches like brute force etc will not work in this case.

Comment: And my second last comment said _"such algorithm present in this challenge"_ not simply _"algorithm"_. This justifies that I am not at all against the coming-up-with-algorithm-ic nature of this challenge. I just feel that the algorithm that the programmer needs to find for this challenge will require more of mathematical skills than programming or code-golfing ones.

Answer (score 7):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>84 79 77</s> 74 bytes

```ruby
->x{y=1;x+="#{x}".reverse.to_i while(2...x).any?{|z|0==y=x%z}&&x%11>0;y>0}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/ruby#TcxLCsIwFIXhuasolRZFDLl5gZQbFyJFHKRYEJUqmjTt2iNSr3T0f2dyGkxb62NAqPwG82X0Y84693Ldw7Hn7dhm73N7cSvBGPNrdrqGfRz6gSMG9EU/lqUvACyvguVjumfNAerFN2KKnAJAVZIoBf9TGk5Umshhp2A2NA3xO5@daSOIyiio0wc)

> If I got it right, when we reach a multiple of 11 we can stop (we will only get multiples of 11 after that)

Comment: There is something more powerful we can prove with the information in the spoiler.

Answer (score 3):

## Python 2, <s>123</s> 110 bytes

Saved 13 bytes thanks to [Ørjan Johansen](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/66041/%C3%98rjan-johansen) and [Wheat Wizard](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/56656/wheat-wizard)!

```
n=input()
while 1:
 if all(n%m for m in range(2,n)):print 1;break
 if n%11==0:print 0;break
 n+=int(`n`[::-1])
```

Returns 1 if it reaches a prime, 0 if it doesn't.
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#NcxBCoMwEEbhvaeYjZDQFjIuIzlJEYwQ62DyV0LE46dFdP09XoUTbHtRujkWiYHYNiQz@RgV2kTzN1MiAWWPT1DdE1rbLQsKcT/l4NczR8vsnLnE3ILH/17UiPFt7YsHXSvzDw)

Answer (score 3):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 65 bytes

`f` takes an `Integer` and returns a `Bool`. `True` means it reaches a prime.

```hs
f n=gcd(product[2..n-1])n<2||gcd 33n<2&&f(n+read(reverse$show n))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/haskell#JcxLCoMwEAbgvadwIZJQGjJJDAj1JKWLYJJWqKPE2G68ux3r5vuHeY1uwG7AHJLrc7Xie8CwiNHNbHlNXxFFCs5z8W/vscTu2Xs2p8mvfb4rIfAKD443tW00KLWmsq4jw8txx1L4hLSE6vhVIuf7DlAAGE1qJQ@1laRpSAmtgTMbSqWKc7OxijTWwA8)

Unfortunately the short but inefficient prime test means that the OP's `True` test cases other than `11` grow too big to finish. But for example 11432 is a `True` case that does finish.

You can also try this 3 bytes longer one, for which TIO can finish all the `True` test cases:

```hs
f n=and[mod n i>0|i<-[2..n-1]]||gcd 33n<2&&f(n+read(reverse$show n))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/haskell#JcxBCoMwEAXQvafIQiRSDJkkCgXtRcRFMLEN1LEktt149zSpm/dh@H9W7XBwuFuv571849OhDWzVLxoe25ctzFttavY/x4XgoNGM62YIEnfjh@ubUTCGDUzTcdxnQ6TEXlTVQvGSp9Tbj/XBlvkdwbqOEaAAUDIpBc/KjidVm@RwVXBmm1KI4my2nUiqTsEP)

Both versions' prime tests break on 1, but it so happens that it gets to a prime (2) anyway.

Otherwise, I noticed about the same thing as G.B. in the spoiler of the Ruby submission:

> Once a number grows to even length, the next iteration will be divisible by 11. Once a number is divisible by 11, so will all following iterations.

Comment: @WheatWizard Well it implies that the number of iterations is bounded, with (sorry, no spoiler tags in comments) max 6 steps to check I think (e.g. 100 is maximal). Trying briefly, this doesn't seem to give me a shorter solution, though. Do you mean something more powerful than that?

Comment: No that was it 6 is the maximum

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>78</s> <s>70</s> 69 bytes

```python
f=lambda x:all(x%a for a in range(2,x))or x%11and f(x+int(`x`[::-1]))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#DckxCoAwDADAr2QpJKhDXISCLxGhkVop1CjFIb@vXe9aWovcRxQwL6WgOYH0VBDIClX0OnEejaiTOWbRCAltyPphsLB5P/FO1N7apQ8v1H4)

## Explanation

This program relies on the fact that

> Every number that loss forever will reach a multiple of 11 in less than 6 moves

This program is a recursive lambda with circuited logical comparatives.  It first checks if n is prime.

```python
all(x%a for a in range(2,x))
```

If this is true we return true.

If it is false we check if it is a multiple of 11.

```python
x%11
```

If false we return false otherwise we return the result of `f` on the next iteration

```python
f(x+int(`x`[::-1]))
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 11 bytes

```
ṚḌ$+$6Ð¡ÆPS
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@/9w56yHO3pUtFXMDk84tPBwW0Dw////DQ1NjA0B)

Comment: For the interest of anyone reading this answer, the last `S` could be a `T` as well. `RD$+$` can also be `+RD$$` or `RD+<newline>Ç` (all trivial modifications)

Comment: @HyperNeutrino I chose `S` because it has less of a chance of showing anything >1. There is no `RD`, just `ṚḌ`, and I chose `ṚḌ$+$` so that I could organize it better.

Comment: I was too lazy to put in the dots; I know why you put `S`; I should have picked that over `T`, but that's mostly for everyone else's interest.

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>14</s> 13 bytes

**EDIT**: Saved one byte because input is reused if there aren't enough elements on the stack

```
[Dp#D11Ö#R+]p
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f8/2qVA2cXQ8PA05SDt2IL//w0NTYwNAQ)

Uses the hint in the question

How it works

```
[              # begin infinite loop
               # implicit input
 D             # duplicate input
  p            # push primality of input
   #           # if prime, break
    D          # duplicate input
     11        # push 11
       Ö       # push input % 11 == 0
        #      # if multiple of 11, break
               # implicit push input
          R    # reverse input
           +   # add both numbers
            ]  # end infinite loop
             p # push primality of result; 1 if prime, 0 if multiple of 11
               # implicit print
```

Answer (score 0):

## MATLAB, <s>88</s> 81 bytes

```
function r=f(n);r=0;for i=1:7 r=r+isprime(n);n=n+str2num(fliplr(num2str(n)));end;
```

Answer (score 0):

### Microsoft Sql Server, <strike>826</strike> 786* bytes

* I've recalled about the IIF function that was introduced in Microsoft Sql Server 2012

```
set nocount on
use rextester
go
if object_id('dbo.n','IF')is not null drop function dbo.n
go
create function dbo.n(@ bigint,@f bigint)returns table as return
with a as(select 0 c union all select 0),b as(select 0 c from a,a t),c as(select 0 c from b,b t),
d as(select 0 c from c,c t),e as(select 0 c from d,d t),f as(select 0 c from e,e t),
v as(select top(@f-@+1)0 c from f)select row_number()over(order by(select 0))+@-1 n from v
go
with u as(select cast(a as bigint)a from(values(11),(11431),(13201),(13360),(13450),(1019410),(1019510),(22),(1431),
(15621),(14641))u(a)),v as(select a,a c from u union all select a,c+reverse(str(c,38))from v
where 0=any(select c%n from dbo.n(2,c/2))and c%11>0)select a,iif(0=any(select max(c)%n from dbo.n(2,max(c)/2)),0,1)
from v group by a option(maxrecursion 0)
```

[Check it online](http://rextester.com/EVXTY29490)

**The more neat formatting**

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;
USE rextester;
GO
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.n', 'IF') IS NOT NULL DROP FUNCTION dbo.n;
GO
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.n(@ BIGINT,@f BIGINT)RETURNS TABLE AS RETURN
  WITH
    a AS(SELECT 0 c UNION ALL SELECT 0),
    b AS(SELECT 0 c FROM a,a t),
    c AS(SELECT 0 c FROM b,b t),
    d AS(SELECT 0 c FROM c,c t),
    e AS(SELECT 0 c FROM d,d t),
    f AS(SELECT 0 c FROM e,e t),
    v AS(SELECT TOP(@f-@+1)0 c FROM f)
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY(SELECT 0))+@-1 n FROM v;
GO
WITH u AS(
  SELECT CAST(a AS BIGINT) a
  FROM(VALUES (11), (11431), (13201), (13360), (13450), (1019410), (1019510),
              (22), (1431), (15621), (14641)) u(a)
),
v AS(
  SELECT a, a c FROM u
    UNION ALL
  SELECT a, c + reverse(str(c, 38))
  FROM v
  WHERE 0 = ANY(SELECT c % n FROM dbo.n(2, c / 2)) AND c % 11 > 0
)
SELECT a, IIF(0 = ANY(SELECT MAX(c) % n FROM dbo.n(2, MAX(c) / 2)), 0, 1)
FROM v
GROUP BY a
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0);
```

Comment: Do you need the `/*true*/` and `/*false*/` comments?

Comment: No. It is the comments that used to separate the input data according to results expected.

Comment: Can you delete them?

Comment: Yes of course, the comments can be deleted.

Comment: You appear to have hard coded the inputs. I'm not too sure, but I think an acceptable input format is selecting them from a table instead

Answer (score 0):

### JavaScript (ES6), 73 bytes

Returns `0` or `true`.

```js
f=n=>{for(d=n;n%--d;);return d<2||n%11&&f(+[...n+''].reverse().join``+n)}
```

#### Commented

This is based on the magic-spoiler formula described by Wheat Wizard.

```js
f = n => {              // given n:
  for(d = n; n % --d;); // find the highest divisor d of n
  return                //
    d < 2 ||            // if this divisor is 1, return true (n is prime)
    n % 11 &&           // else: if 11 is a divisor of n, return 0
    f(                  // else: do a recursive call with
      +[...n + '']      // the digits of n
      .reverse().join`` // reversed, joined,
      + n               // coerced to a number and added to n
    )                   //
}                       //
```

#### Test cases

I've removed the two largest inputs from the snippet, as they take a few seconds to complete. (But they do work as well.)

```js
f=n=>{for(d=n;n%--d;);return d<2||n%11&&f(+[...n+''].reverse().join``+n)}

console.log(f(11))      // -> True
console.log(f(11431))   // -> True
console.log(f(13201))   // -> True
console.log(f(13360))   // -> True
console.log(f(13450))   // -> True
console.log(f(22))      // -> False
console.log(f(1431))    // -> False
console.log(f(15621))   // -> False
console.log(f(14641))   // -> False
```

Answer (score 0):

## Mathematica, 45 bytes

```
Or@@PrimeQ@NestList[#+IntegerReverse@#&,#,6]&
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 9 bytes

```
ṚḌ+Ɗ6Ð¡ẒẸ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hzlkPd/RoH@syOzzh0MKHuyY93LXj/@H2R01r/v83NNQxNDQxBpLGRgYg0tjMAEiamAJJA0NLE0MIbQqkjYx0ICpNzYyApImZiSEA)

#### How it works

```
ṚḌ+Ɗ6Ð¡ẒẸ    Monadic main link.
ṚḌ+Ɗ         Monad: Reverse and add to original.
    6Ð¡      Repeatedly apply the above 6 times, collecting all iterations
       ẒẸ    Is any of them a prime?
```

Answer (score 0):

[PHP](http://php.net/) **114 bytes**

```
<?php function f($n){$n1=strrev((string)$n);$r=$n+(int)$n1;for($i=2;$i<$r;$i++){if($r%$i==0){die('0');}}die('1');}
```

More readable version:

```
<?php function f($n)
{
    $n1 = strrev((string)$n);
    $r = $n + (int)$n1;
    for ($i = 2; $i < $r; $i++) {
        if ($r % $i == 0) {
            die('0');
        }
    }
    die('1');
}

f(11431 );
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VYwxDsIwDEX3nMKDUR11aYCtjThMaYgXJwqFBfXswVGRKv7wLb9nOcdc63TLMZvwknnlJBAIxX4MaFAceHiupSxvIp0sD6t23G1RiQI9EMuq3O08pELI/jwiT1i0@/73r4X1fzkhg/cwWDhEyzLHBMP4x9q9PdBmjr7zQp3r1G7GBHLuenGgW631Cw)

I used [this](https://mothereff.in/byte-counter) thing for counting bytes.

Comment: Ah okay, it should terminate. I misunderstood the question then. Edited the question to terminate for false-y cases.

Comment: Now it always returns false unless the first reverse is a prime. You're also not checking the first case, where \$n\$ is a prime. And TIO has a byte counter for you... it even has an auto-formatter for the submission template that you can use